# Data Table with AJAX, sum and add total footer

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, datatable, datatables

I have a datatable created by the following code

```
    var data = results.rows;
    var column_names = results.headers;

    if (column_names) {
        var columns = [];
        var total = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < column_names.length; i++) {
             columns[i] = {
                  'title': column_names[i],
                  'data': i
            }
        };

        dataTable=$('#report').DataTable( {
            columns: columns,
            data: data,
            paging: false,
            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            buttons: [
                'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
            ]
        }
        );
        showTable();
        dataTable.columns.adjust().draw();
    } else {
        alert('No Results Found');
    }
```

I would like to add a footer to the table that contains a sum of the 2nd column and has text that says "Total: "

The table in the html looks like:

```
    <table id="report" class="compact"> 
    </table>
```

I tried adding a footer in html but it was overwritten when the report is rerun so this needs to be done in the top section of code in order to display every time a table is created.

Thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found an example here [http://jsbin.com/putiyep/edit?js](http://jsbin.com/putiyep/edit?js,output).

It wont look as pretty as you hoped for but it'll do the job.
It leverages the `footerCallback` of the API and use the column index of the table and basic math to return your total.

The data table section of the code would look like:

```
dataTable=$('#report').DataTable( {
        columns: columns,
        data: data,
        paging: false,
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        "footerCallback": function (tfoot, data, start, end, display) {
            var api = this.api();
            var p = api.column(2).data().reduce(function (a, b) {
                return a + b;
            }, 0)
            $(api.column(2).footer()).html("Total: "+p);
        },
        buttons: [
            'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
        ]
    }
);
```

Comment: I pasted the code in and got an error "DataTables warning: table id=report - Cannot reinitialise DataTable. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/3"

Comment: The concsole in browser returns an error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'sDefaultContent' of undefined" could this be because the BigDecimal typing in the data?

Comment: Nevermind, i had to change the column numbering! it works great thanks!